# Asp.Net GridView - Can we display the footer template in the grid as first row?

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

We are using Asp:Gridview in our application and use FooterTemplate to add rows dynamically to the grid. However, the footer template will be as the last row in the grid.

As our grid involves paging and custom record count, user might have to scoll down always for adding a new record in the grid. Hence, need to show the footer template at the top of the grid.

Searched in multiple sources, but could not find a similar implementation. Most of the places, could see the Footer template used, but adding a new record would display at the bottom.

In fact, found a suggestion in one of the post to use HeaderTemplate and modify the styling. However, I believe the header template should be used in order to add sub-headers etc
Request your assistance

Comment: You tagged this question as aspxgridview. Did you read the tag description for that? It's for a DevExpress control. Are you using DevExpress? If not, you should remove that tag from your question.

Comment: try to have a look at FlexyPager. It might has something u need. https://github.com/adriancs2/FlexyPager.net

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, often going with a simple itemtemplate, and NOT using in-line editing is often less messy.

and your data pager should not show more rows then what a typical screen should show.

And it not a lot of code either, and you wind up with a whole lot less messy markup.

Toss in jQuery.UI dialog, (again only a few extra lines of code), and the result is thus this:

[image]

So, using some extra row in the grid winds up taking extra space, but worse tends to take more messy code anyway.

And the UI to edit a record, add a record is the SAME, so users experience less of a learning curve to edit a record, or add a new record.

And you also thus clean up the grid, and the buttons to edit or cancel are removed from the main GV, again providing a clean UI, and one that users will find far easier to use.

Either way, the gv pager should not require the user to scroll down to see/use/enjoy the data pager.